As a first line manger, what can I do when the company's financial difficulties are affecting my team's morale and productivity?
My employer is in finance difficulty. The company has cut salaries (including mine), has eliminated the team-building budget and other allowances, and is laying people off. The management says it is temporary, but as a first line manager I can see that it's affecting morale and performance to the point that my team's productivity is low.
To borrow the latest term, they become "ghost engineers" to some level. I can see they are not focus on their tasks and they use social media at office from time to time. (BTW, we don't require employees to not use social media at all during office time as that is impossible.)
Now I basically look the other way when they do that as long as they do not go too far. But are there other things I can do to make their productivity not fall too low? I think the last thing they need now is a pep talk at least not from me.

"they use social media at office from time to time" So what? Everyone does. Occasional breaks are needed to mind workers (as well as for anyone). "we don't require employees to not use social media at all during office time as that is impossible" That pretty much cancels the need of the second paragraph.

I voted to close because the it cannot be answered shortly, and because there is no specific problem to be answered. Shortly, the question is: "Please tell me the science of motivation."

You find out why  their productivity is low. Lack of motivation can be caused by a lot of different things, but it happens for a reason. Quite often company policies or management is the culprit.

I agree with Virolinos point - as written the question is too broad, too opinion based and does not have a clear goal aside from how to motivate your staff. This has some elements that could turn it into a great question, but to do so, we are going to need to narrow it down the scope to something we can answer.

I'm not sure exactly what connection you're trying to draw between these two issues. Why do you think that the company's financial problems have anything to do with your team's (perceived) low productivity?

My question was closed so I don't bother to update my question but if you are interested why there is a connection or why I don't think my question is too broad, please my comment to @mxyzplk's answer.

@Qiulang邱朗 The comments address my confusion. I hope it's ok that I edited those details into the question. I retracted my downvote and voted to reopen.

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine thanks. I changed the words unacceptably low to just low and "actively laying off" to just "laying off".  BTW, even though it is highly unlikely my boss and colleagues will see this post I don't want to say bad things about them, just the fact. Probably one of reasons I did not add those details to my question at the first.

You can’t affect the overall finances of the company.  So what do you do? You do the same things as when your team members' productivity is low anytime else.

Lead by example
Set clear expectations and treat people fairly
Encourage, recognize, and reward achievements and efforts publicly
Coach team members 1-1/privately
Set up team constructs and expectations like agile to allow the team to encourage and support each other
Address performance problems with more mentoring, then a PIP, then termination as applicable
Hire good people to fill the gaps

It's unclear whether their poor performance existed before as well, if so it could be a cause of not a result of the company's problems, and if it's just now then maybe it's a result of but going to be the cause of further problems. You get paid to be a manager to fix that, just like they are still getting paid to do their work.  There's no free rides, whether the company is doing "great" or "in difficulty."  And frankly, the lack of line managers' ability to handle that is what makes upper managers have to wield coarse grained solutions like layoffs, where you may have to rid yourself of a different set of staff than you'd prefer from a performance point of view.
You're a manager, manage.
"Overall company health" is an excuse like any other to not do your job. I've led high performing teams in fast growing orgs and in painfully stagnant orgs and in orgs having layoffs. All of those have their own challenges - none of them are an excuse for not putting in your best effort on the clock. If people don’t want to work in the environment for the pay they should leave - and that’s a rational choice - but while there workers need to work and managers need to manage, and you seem unaware of basic performance management principles so it’s a good time to learn.

The trouble comes with "Hire good people to fill the gaps" - if the company is in financial difficulty, you don't get to hire anybody; it might (emphasis on "might") be better for the team to keep the poor performers rather than have nobody.

And build the team cohesion through low-cost team building events. Things like going out for a happy hour together, bringing in food for a "potluck", celebrating birthdays or other holidays with cookies and cake are all part of building team comradery. Make the team survival more important than the company survival.

So basically "be a good manager". Which I might add does not involve useless crap like "offsite team building events", but rather is focusing on the day to day activities. They lack motivation because their work situation is bad or boring, not because they didn't do enough strange teambuilding exercises nor because they weren't given enough snacks.

I left out some details because I felt it may sidetrack my question but with your comments I see that maybe a mistake: 1. my salary is cut in half for a year 2. all the allowance  and all team building fee have cancelled 3. the company keeps laying off people. So none of your suggestions are valid but as the question was closed, it does not matter.

@Qiulang邱朗 those were very important details in my opinion. Their low productivity is can easily be explained through this uncertainty with their job security. Their perks are taken off, their colleagues getting laid off, I am pretty sure they consider this company as a ship about to be sunk.

@Qiulang邱朗 When layoffs happen, they impact the productivity of those left behind. Managing the expectations of those left is a challenge and requires that you offer a vision of the future either with this company or that the team moves together to a different company. When you can't offer either, then watch the team break up and leave.

That was why I didn't think my question was too broad. I am only paid half of my salary and my team's productivity is low so what can I do ?

@Qiulang邱朗 Either find another job or do something that will find work for the whole company.

@Qiulang邱朗 Company sounds like it is in a death spiral. I would polish my resume, and start looking while you still have an income.

I have an analogy from military history: in retreats units which lost their morale, perished or got routed almost immediately, while ones that maintained their discipline most of the times had a big percentage of survival rate.
I would argue to them that they should remain productive more when the company is going down.

It will make it easier if they are productive to keep that momentum while applying elsewhere if they do it while working
It will stop the downward spiral, at least for them and the people around them
They will have more things to "sell" to the next employer: "not only I am a good employee but also when the company was under pressure, I did not crack"
It will make them healthier as the emotional stress will not get to their bodies/psyche
... and if the company turns around and goes well, but also acquired, or anything, they should ask to be rewarded for this stance


"they should ask to be rewarded for this stance" The chance of this happening is just about zero and everybody knows this.

@PhilipKendall Financial difficulty is not necessarily a death sentence; while some companies fold, others survive it and grow to be stronger than ever.  (I speak from experience.)

@gidds The point I'm making is that companies do not look at the people who stuck at it when the going was tough and reward them. Maybe they should, but they don't and that's the reality of the world.
